# Azure DevOps: How to find all release plans where a variable group is linked to

Tags: azure-devops, release

I want to reorganize my variable groups in Azure DevOps, but before I delete any variable groups I want to make sure they are not used anymore. Also I need to link the newly created groups to old releases.

I could go over all release definitions and check which definition is linked to which variable groups, but there should be a more easy way for me show if a variable group still has linked releases. But I cannot seem to find that overview.

Is there an overview like above of will this be a pain in the ... to reorganize?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see it available either, from the front-end or documented as available from the API.  I think your only option is the one you mentioned to loop over the definitions to validate.

Looking at Task groups, they included a References tab which is probably what you want just on the Variable group.  I'd recommend creating a feature request for this on the [developer community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/index.html).